# Java Frame duplicated without applying change

Tags: java, swing, oop, jframe

I have 2 frames from different class, one is the main frame containing just a jbutton and jtextfield, and the other one contains a the setting to change the background color of the first frame, so i've a problem because when i clicked the the button OK button the color changed but it created a new main frame with new change instead of applying the change in the active main frame.

here is the main frame code

```
package com.srccodes.example;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Cheb extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cheb cheb = new Cheb();

}

JTextArea about = new JTextArea(3,30);

JButton callB = new JButton("Settings");
Cheb(){
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20,25));
    setSize(400,400);
    setTitle("Check Box");
    

    add(new Label("About you"));
    JScrollPane aboutScroll= new JScrollPane(about);
    add(aboutScroll);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(callB);
    setVisible(true);
    callB.addActionListener(this);
    
    
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    
     
    //Countinent selection with Check Box
     if(e.getSource() == callB)
     {
         CollorClass cl =new CollorClass();
     }
    
    
}

}
```

here is the code to change the color of the main frame

```
package com.srccodes.example;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class CollorClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CollorClass cc = new CollorClass();

}
 JLabel bg = new JLabel("Background Color"); 
 String colorName[] = {"None","RED","GREEN","BLACK","BLUE","YELLOW","WHITE"};
 JComboBox bgColor = new JComboBox(colorName);
 JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
CollorClass()
{
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20,25));
    setSize(400,400);
    setTitle("Check Box");
    add(bg);
    add(bgColor);
    add(ok);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    ok.addActionListener(this);
    
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    if(e.getSource() == ok)
    {
        Cheb cheb = new Cheb();
        String SelectedValue = bgColor.getSelectedItem().toString();
        switch (SelectedValue){
            case "RED" :
                cheb.about.setBackground(Color.red);
                System.out.print(SelectedValue);
                break;
            case "YELLOW" :
                cheb.about.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                System.out.print(SelectedValue);
                break;
            case "BLUE" :
                cheb.about.setBackground(Color.blue);
                System.out.print(SelectedValue);
                break;
        
            case "GREEN" :
                cheb.about.setBackground(Color.green);
                System.out.print(SelectedValue);
                break;
            case "BLACK" :
                cheb.about.setBackground(Color.black);
                System.out.print(SelectedValue);
                break;
            case "WHITE" :
                cheb.about.setBackground(Color.white);
                System.out.print(SelectedValue);
                break;
        
        
            default:
                
                System.out.print(SelectedValue);
        }
    }
    
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is, you are invoking a new instance of the `Cheb` class when you select a color. So you are not changing the color of the initial window, but of the new window.

It is specifically this line in the `CollorClass`'s `actionPerformed` method that is causing the issue:

```
Cheb cheb = new Cheb();
```

What you instead might want to do is inject the `Cheb` class as a dependency into the `CollorClass`. This way, you can invoke methods and get to properties of the initial `Cheb` class.

One way of doing that could be as follows (the ellipsis '...' dots are used to hide unnecessary code):

CollorClass:

```
public class CollorClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private final Cheb cheb;

    ...

    CollorClass(Cheb cheb) // important addition
    {
        this.cheb = cheb; // important addition

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20,25));
        setSize(400,400);
        setTitle("Check Box");
        add(bg);
        add(bgColor);
        add(ok);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        ok.addActionListener(this);

    }

    ...
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == ok)
        {
            // No instantiation of new Cheb here anymore.
            // Using the dependency instead.

            String SelectedValue = bgColor.getSelectedItem().toString();
            switch (SelectedValue){
                case "RED" :
                    cheb.about.setBackground(Color.red);
                    System.out.print(SelectedValue);
                    break;
                case "YELLOW" :

                ...
        }
```

Cheb:

```
public class Cheb extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    ...

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {


        //Countinent selection with Check Box
        if(e.getSource() == callB)
        {
            CollorClass cl = new CollorClass(this); // Pass this Cheb instance as argument
        }


    }
```

Hope that it's clear. It still could use improvements (e.g. closing one window will close both windows), but that might be a next challenge to figure out!

Comment: Good answer. :) *"It still could use improvements (e.g. closing one window will close both windows), but that might be a next challenge to figure out!"* Use a modal `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane` instead of one of the frames would be how I'd approach it.

Comment: I find a way(closing one window will close both windows), by changing the from `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` to `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` in CollorClass;

Comment: Thank you! Glad it helped OP :) those are indeed both great options to tackle the closing-every-window issue.